# I don't understand the role of the に particle in this sentence?

Tags: particles, particle-に

The definition of 募集【ぼしゅう】 given in an article by NHK News Web Easy is

> 人や作品などを、大勢の人に呼びかけて集めること.

I don't know what is the role of the に particle in that sentence, is it marking the subject of the action, or is it rethorical? How should it be interpreted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Santiago, 「大勢の人**に**呼びかけて」 reads like a clause to me, within the sentence 「人や作品などを集めること.」 ...   Although if that were the case I'm not sure why they wouldn't just write it as  「大勢の人**に**呼びかけて、人や作品などを集めること.」

in any case, I parse this definition as "to gather people or items by calling out **to** a large group of people"

Comment: `を集まる` はダメです・・・「集**ま**る」は自動詞ですので・・・「集**め**る」に直してあげてね・・・・・

Answer (score 0):

In general the に{ni} particle has 2 main uses:

- To mark a location:

> 駅{えき}**に**います。
>
> I am **at** the station.

- To mark a recipient:

> 田中{たなか}さんは私{わたし}**に**飴{あめ}をくれました。
>
> Tanaka San gave candy **to** me.
>
> 私{わたし}は田中{たなか}さん**に**英語{えいご}を教{おし}えました。
>
> I taught English language **to** Tanaka San.

In the example, に is being used to mark a group of people as the recipient of this action. Perhaps to “shout” **at**, “call” **to** or  to “rally” (e.g., “rally the troops”).